# What's the best way to access the DOM ref immediately after the element is being toggled on?

Tags: javascript, reactjs

Consider this component:

```
function Component() {
  const [show, setShow] = useState(false);
  const ref = useRef(null);

  return (
    <div>
      <button
        onClick={() => {
          setShow(true);
          console.log(ref.current); // -> null
          setTimeout(() => {
            console.log(ref.current); // -> <div>123</div>
          }, 0);
        }}
      >
        show
      </button>
      {show && <div ref={ref}>oh hi!</div>}
    </div>
  );
}
```

The ref object will be empty since the object will only be inserted on next re-render. Is there a better way to access the dom ref than `setTimeout`?

Answer (score 0):

Use the `useEffect()` hook which runs after each update (as well as the when the component mounts).

[CodeSandbox](https://codesandbox.io/s/wizardly-violet-wjecj7?file=/src/Component.js)

Read more about it [here](https://reactjs.org/docs/hooks-effect.html)

> **What does useEffect do?** By using this Hook, you tell React that your component needs to do something after render. React will remember the function you passed (we’ll refer to it as our “effect”), and call it later after performing the DOM updates.

> **Does useEffect run after every render?** Yes! By default, it runs both after the first render and after every update.

```js
export default function Component() {
  const [show, setShow] = useState(false);
  const ref = useRef(null);

  useEffect(() => {
    console.log(ref.current);
  }, [show]);

  return (
    <div>
      <button
        onClick={() => {
          setShow(true);
        }}
      >
        show
      </button>
      {show && <div ref={ref}>oh hi!</div>}
    </div>
  );
}
```